# unix cronjob for wordpress does not stop running

Tags: cron

So i disabled wp-cron, and added one in my crontab.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON',true);
```

---

```
*/45 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/wp-cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This works fine, but every so often, i just get one that does not quit.

```
7625 root      20   0  513m  79m  20m R 99.8  2.0 189:42.39 php   
[ec2-user@www ~]$ ps -o etime= -p 7625
   03:01:45
```

And it's sucking up max cpu and eventually steal time (i'm on a shared environment). I don't know what's going on here. Should I let it run? Is it doing stuff that is backlogged?

I'd really appreciate some insight and help with this.

Thanks,

Comment: It's not possible to tell what it's doing from just what's in your question without knowing what kind of cron jobs are running, that might require a full copy of your codebase, there's still more debugging to do. Look into cron control, and try to look at the output of the cronjob rather than silencing its output, as well as your PHP error logs

Comment: Additionally, try to run the PHP process as a non-priviledged user rather than root, for security reasons

Comment: Yeah i'll try to run it without suppressing the output.

Comment: i got another one, not running in quiet mode, but still not getting any output. I did a strace on it to catch any system calls it's making, but nothing shows up.